# Checking membership in an array without for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, vectorization

I want to simplify this code to working without for loop.

```
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        if ismember(j,A)

           PID(i,i)=TFP(i,j)+ PID(i,i);

        end
    end
end
```

in which `A` is a matrix that contains some labels. I previously stored `TFP` in the form of N*N sparse double. So, I came up with the following solution but I couldn't find a way to implement membership condition (Specified by ?) in that.

```
PID = sum(TFP).*(?);
```

Can it be implemented without a loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `ismember(j,A)` is equivalent of just using the values of `A` to index. So you can use that and completely avoid the `ismember` function (which is by far the slowest part of the code).

So a first step for optimization is

```
A2=unique(A); % just in case you do not do this already
for i=1:N
    for j=A2
        PID(i,i)=TFP(i,j)+ PID(i,i);
    end
end
```

This should be already very fast. Loops are not bad in MATLAB and get heavily optimized by the JIT compiler.

The next step to optimization is to get all the indices together and remove the secondary loop. You can do this with linear indexing, so

```
A2=unique(A); % just in case you do not do this already
for i=1:N
    PID(i,i)=sum(TFP(i,A2));
end
```

And finally, you can get rid of this by diagonalizing the sum of the desired columns:

```
A2=unique(A); % just in case you do not do this already
PID=diag(sum(TFP(:,A2),2));
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of summing the result of element-wise multiplication you can use matrix multiplication. It computes the sum of products without creating a temporary array:

```
J = ismember(1:N, A).';
PID = diag(TFP * J);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure i completely uderstand your problem
Have you tried this?

```
j=1:N;
PID = sum(TFP).*ismember(j,A);
```

ismember would work as a matrix that when is true is equal to'1' so it would allow to multiply.

Comment: [I didn't downvote, I think this answer is almost there]. This will output a row vector, the OP's summation was always collated on the index `(i,i)`, i.e. on the diagonal. I think you'll end up out by a factor of `N` too, since the OP repeats the check for `i = 1:N`, which you've removed