# Loop optimization with row-wise sum

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization

Aiming at optimizing following nested loop, the problem is how to deal with need for row-wise sum.

```
for i=1:N
for j=1:N
    F(i,i)=(exp(-B(j,j))) * P(i,j)+ F(i,i);
end
end
```

Specifically, I want to eliminate loops and it looks achievable according to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60323652/optimizing-three-nested-loops-with-multiple-calculation-in-matlab) but the problem is how to store changing value of `F` in each iteration.

I come up with this idea :

```
for j=1:N
    F(:)=(exp(-B(j,j))) * P(:,j)+ F(:);
end
```

Using this solution, F will be overwritten in every iteration!!  Any idea?

Comment: What are the sizes of `F`, `B` and `P`? What is the value of `N`?

Comment: @SardarUsama, All the matrices are `NxN` and `N=300`.

Comment: Do you really mean `F(i,i)=...`? That never assigns any values to the off-diagonal elements of `F`? Why not make `F` a vector then? And you only ever use the diagonal elements of `B`, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code can be simplified to the code like below

```
F = diag(P*exp(-diag(B)));
```

**Example**

```
N = 3;
B = rand(N,N);
P = rand(N,N);

F = zeros(N);
for i=1:N
for j=1:N
    F(i,i)=(exp(-B(j,j))) * P(i,j)+ F(i,i);
end
end

d = isequal(F,diag(P*exp(-diag(B)))); % check if F is identical to diag(P*exp(-diag(B)))
```

such that

```
>> d
d = 1 % indicating that they are identical
```